# Issue with polynomial regression function in Ruby

Tags: ruby, math, matrix, regression

I've had trouble finding a good Ruby library for regression, so I've written my own function for polynomial regression.  I'm getting curves that look somewhat correct on occasion, but most of the time the curve is way off.

```
def self.polynomial_regression(x, y, degree, options = {})
  x_data = x.map { |xi| (0..degree).map { |pow| (xi**pow).to_f } }

  mx = Matrix[*x_data]
  my = Matrix.column_vector(y)

  poly = ((mx.t * mx).inv * mx.t * my).transpose.to_a[0]

  result = {}
  result[:fn] = Proc.new do |x|
    return nil if x.nil?
    if x.kind_of?(Array)
      x.collect { |v|
        if v.nil?
          nil
        else
          poly.each_with_index.map{ |p, i|
            p*(v**i)
          }.reduce(:+)
        end
      }
    else
      poly.each_with_index.map{ |p, i|
        p*(x**i)
      }.reduce(:+)
    end
  end

  result
end
```

There's a math error somewhere in here, I'm just not sure where it is.

The `poly` variable contains the coefficients for the regression.  I then use that to generate a function using `poly` and the input `x` values where I multiply each coefficient `p` and `x` value, and raise it to the proper exponent `i`.

```
poly.each_with_index.map{ |p, i|
    p*(x**i)
}.reduce(:+)
```

I'm not a statistics expert by any means, but I think this is the correct math.  Is there a mistake somewhere in my logic, or have I made an error in the implementation?

Comment: Please give a concrete example of "the curve is way off", showing the desired and actual output, as in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: About debugging this, (1) try to separate the calculation of the coefficients from computing the polynomial for given x and coefficients. If you know the coefficients, can you construct the polynomial function? Look at that first before going into the calculation of the coefficients. (2) Try using data for which you know what the coefficients should be. E.g. select some arbitrary coefficients, generate outputs, use that as your data. You should get back the same coefficients. FWIW the formulas appear to be correct although I didn't look at it too terribly carefully.

Answer (score 1):

```
   def regress x, y, degree
        x_data = x.map { |xi| (0..degree).map { |pow| (xi**pow).to_r } }
       
        mx = Matrix[*x_data]
        my = Matrix.column_vector(y)
       
        ((mx.t * mx).inv * mx.t * my).transpose.to_a[0].map(&:to_f)
      end
```

Method

```
p regress([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
          [1, 6, 17, 34, 57, 86, 121, 162, 209, 262, 321],
          2)
```

Output

[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]